# Is half of depletion region a part of N region or P region?

Tags: electrical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials, chemical-engineering

Is it correct to say that if the P-N junction is in the middle of the depletion region, half of the depletion region is for the P region and the other half is for the N region?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not true. The depletion region width depends on the doping.  You can think that the non-moving +charge ("the bound charge") in the depleted N side has as much charge as the depleted area in the P side has non-moving minus charge. Lower doping means wider depletion zone and there can be very different dopings in the N and P halves.

The same is explained with some equations here [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P–n_junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction)